# Box2d:apply velocity in a direction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I apply impulse in an object in box2d iPhone app and now want to increase its speed in particuler direction....i mean i need two thing

1.through the object in a direction
2.increase speed

plz help..

Answer (score 2):

```
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(xAcceleration, yAcceleration);
force *= dt;  // Use this if your game engine uses an explicit time step
b2Vec2 p = myObjectBody->GetWorldPoint(b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
body->ApplyForce(force, p);
```

By modifying `xAcceleration` and `yAcceleration`, you can make the object move with various speeds in different directions. (If you calculate angles, you might want to use `force.Normalize();` and then multiply by a velocity.)

Comment: very very thanx......can u provide me the link of best books for box2d
iPhone..??i want to buy one..

Comment: but i have another question....i think in the above code p is the direction of force....isn't it??then if i want to direct it in X or -X
 or Y -Y axises then what to do??

Comment: plz look at..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385056/box2dgradually-increase-velocity-problem

Answer (score 0):

```
b2Vec2 vector = self.speed * b2Vec2(cos(angle), sin(angle));
self.yourbodyBody->SetLinearVelocity(vector);
[self schedule:@selector(increaseSpeed) interval:0.1];

- (void)increaseSpeed
{
    self.speed += 0.01;
    float angle = self.yourbodyBody->GetAngle();
    b2Vec2 vector = self.speed * b2Vec2(cos(angle), sin(angle));
    self.yourbodyBody->SetLinearVelocity(vector);
}
```

Comment: You could improve this if you added a bit of explanation.